# Переход из activity в fragment(tab5)

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, android-intent

Есть приложение, с 5 фрагментами, Tab1-Tab5. В 5 фрагменте, есть перенос на регистрацию,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Ienac.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
```

А в activity регистрации, есть кнопка back

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ienac);

     Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
     back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tab5.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
     });
 }
```

Смотря темы на форуме, говорили что переход во фрагменты используется так

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tab5.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Но он сразу же выдает ошибку.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(".Tab5");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

А такой код выдаёт ошибку уже после нажатия кнопки.

Как следует правильно переходить из activity в фрагменты? Смотря то, что мне требуется сразу 5 фрагмент?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tab5.class) - здесь вместо класа фрагмента поставь клас активности которая контейнерит этот фрагмент.

Comment: Вы из 5-го фрагмента открываете активность и в него же хотите вернуться? Тогда под кнопкой `back` просто закройте её: `finish()`, вместо запуска нового интента.

Comment: У вас неверная реализация. Что бы вызвать фрагмент его нужно открывать в родительской активности. В каком либо контейнере. Почитайте базу про фрагменты. Так оно работать не будет.